# Xcode (10.7) -- clGetProgramBinaries results unreadable

Tags: osx-lion, opencl

I have an OpenCL kernel that runs well but I want to look at the intermediate code.  I use getprograminfo to pull out the binary and save it to a text file.  I've tried this with nVidia, AMD, an i7 and a Xeon.

In all of these cases the binary is unreadable.

I understand that on OS X the chunk of data returned is actually a binary plist.  I've found instructions for using plutil to convert it to xml, and they work.

It's still unreadable ... though I've seen instructions online that this is where you find the PTX code (in the case of my AMD 5870).  There's the expected clBinaryData key but the data under that key is still one big chunk of stuff, not readable IL instructions in text form.

I'd really like to examine the intermediate language to assess inefficiencies in my use of the gpu.  Is this simply not possible under Xcode?  Or, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any information!...

Answer (score 1):

If you run your program with following environmental variable set you should see .IL and .ISA files in your directory.

```
$ GPU_DUMP_DEVICE_KERNEL=3 ./my-program
```

Another way is to use [AMD APP Kernel Analyzer](http://developer.amd.com/sdks/AMDAPPSDK/downloads/Pages/default.aspx) (which comes along with AMD APP SDK) to look at the Intermediate file i.e IL and ISA.
(I am not sure whether AMD APP SDK available for MAC or not).

One more option according to APP SDK documentation, put the below in your host code.

```
putenv("GPU_DUMP_DEVICE_KERNEL=3");
```

References

1. [AMD OpenCL Programming Guide](http://www.ljll.math.upmc.fr/groupes/gpgpu/tutorial/ATI_Stream_SDK_OpenCL_Programming_Guide.pdf)
2. [AMD Devgurus forum](http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/138267)

Comment: Well, thanks very much for that; it does look as if it _should_ work, at least on Linux, but I haven't yet made it work on OS X.  At least I now know how to set env vars 3 different ways -- putenv, setenv, and by editing the scheme in Xcode to include a variable name and value.  None work yet.  If I can figure how to put your first example into a unix shell I'll try that, though I imagine that's what "edit scheme" is doing.  Maybe not possible under OSX without in-house tools on the Apple campus?  Can't imagine their devs don't have that capability....

Comment: ... it looks like I can also set an environment var in ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist, then log out and in again, and *everybody* gets it forever.  I'll try that when I get home (right now I only have my laptop with nV mobile GPU) and if that doesn't do it, I might think the env var isn't gonna do it for me at all....

Comment: thank you, ocluser!; you sent me on a fun learning spree even though it doesn't seem to do it for osx.  see my own answer above for more info than you want to read....

Answer (score 0):

(Making this a top-level answer so I can do some formatting.)

ocluser's answer was very helpful, in that it was enlightening and caused great learning, though it did not, alas, solve the problem.

I've verified that the environment variable described *is* being set, and is available to my application when run from within xcode.  However, it does not have (under OSX) the highly desirable effect it has under Linux.

But, I now know how to set environment variables in 7 of 8 different ways.  I also set "tracer" envars to tell me which methods are effective within the scope of my application.  From the below, you can see that both the method of "edit scheme" to add arguments works, as does the "putenv" suggested by ocluser.  What didn't set it in that scope: ~/.MACOS/environment.plist, app-specific plist, .profile, and adding a build phase to run a custom script (I found at least one other way within xcode to set one but forgot what I called the tracer and can't find it now; maybe it's on another machine....)

GPU_DUMP_DEVICE_KERNEL is 3

GPU_DUMP_TRK_ENVPLIST is (null)

GPU_DUMP_TRK_APPPLIST is (null)

GPU_DUMP_TRK_DOTPROFILE is (null)

GPU_DUMP_TRK_RUNSCRIPT is (null)

GPU_DUMP_TRK_SCHARGS is 1

GPU_DUMP_TRK_PUTENV is 1

... so, no this doesn't really *answer* the question, but expands on it a bit.  Sorry if poor form.  Thanks!

Have not given up and shall provide an actual problem-solver if I find one.